# Unknown publisher + browser download wanrning

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

im new to dot net and has created an application with setup.exe
Im facing 2 issues
First, when downloading the setup.exe the macafee web scan says that this file might be harmfull and the user has to take the risk and install it.

2nd, after downloading and when trying to install the setup.exe the windows warn the user that this file is with unknown publisher and the user also should take the risk and proceed

The setup.exe is created using install shield limited edition

My question is: what should i do to get rid of these 2 problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have to Sign you product to get rid of these two problems. Read more here:

[How to sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool)

Comment: Ok thanks ill look into it, this should work for windows  forms app, correct? I mean this is mot for windows store apps only right?

Comment: yes you can sign a windows app too, however you will need to buy a code signing certificate. what I mean is that, this won't be free